# Is there a pre-GORM init hook in Grails?

Tags: grails

I'm trying to address a very specific requirement in our Grails 2.5.x application: I'd like to upgrade the database schema before the application starts by applying a series of database conversion scripts (depending on the DB version / app version). We did this in the past in a "traditional" Java Servlet app, but I'm struggling with Grails a bit.

**Question:** is there an event, in Grails, that I could somehow hook into during the app startup that would allow me to use Groovy and existing DataSource configuration, yet would occur before the GORM/Hibernate starts up?

Some options I've already checked:

- BootStrap's init closure wouldn't work here, as the app simply wouldn't start with the "validate" mode if the database schema was out of date.
- There's Events.groovy that I haven't used before, but it seems these events are aimed at grails compile/build lifecycle rather than the self-contained application packaged in a WAR file and deployed to an app container.
- The grails [database-migration](https://grails.org/plugin/database-migration) plugin seems to be similar and expects Grails command line to be available on the target server, <s>and the conversion to be performed manually by the administrator</s>. *It turns out I was most likely wrong here.*

Comment: Actually you can have database migrations run automatically on startup of the app and not be purely manual. I recommend you take another look at the plugin, since it is exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you Joshua - I'll check it out! Maybe I got the wrong idea after a quick read of the plugin description.

Comment: grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['your-db-specific-changelog-filename.groovy']   <-- all revisions of our database are done through migration scripts. We have different scripts depending on h2, Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL.  database-migration is generally very capable.

Answer (score 0):

While I haven't really found a way to hook into the Grails startup before the GORM startup takes place (and performs database validation or creation) there is a way to perform custom database migration code via BootStrap init simply by disabling all of Hibernate's hbm2ddl (just omit any of the valid dbCreate values).

For our project, we ended up using the **database-migration** plugin, but I soon realized that for it to work properly, you would also have to disable hhm2ddl. If the `validate` option was used, GORM would attempt to validate the database *before* the database-migration took place, and the app would not start.

So the same approach could be used if one wanted to provide custom implementation of database upgrade/migration code - disabling hbm2ddl would allow it to run without interfering with hibernate's database schema validations. The obvious drawback is that the validation mode can no longer be used.